# Wifi diagnostic tool

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi3

I am working on a room which contains 6 wifi IP cameras. There are also the same wifi IP cameras in other close rooms. This cameras have their own wifi access point. I can't manage anything on this wifi network.

I have a raspberry Model 3 in this room. I tried to set up a wifi access point on this raspberry.

I can't connect to this access point, but if in unplug everything and go to try far away from this rooms, everything works great.

So i am wondering if the raspberry is not disturbed by this big wifi traffic.

What should i do ?

Here is an extract of my /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Do you see something i can change in order to make it work ?

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=XXXX
hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=XXXXXXX
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the channel=6 to channel=1 in your config file. This should help if the wifi cameras are using channel 6 as well.

https://www.lifewire.com/best-wifi-channels-for-your-network-818278

Comment: Thanks in fact i do not know which channel are used for cameras. Is there a tool i can install on my raspberry in order to see paquet count for each channel/bandwidth ? Thanks

Comment: There are quite a few wifi analyzers available depending on the OS you want to run it from. There are some for mobile devices as well.
https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wifi-analyzer-acrylic-professional/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Android phone handy you could try installing a WiFi Analyzer app, e.g. [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en) or else you may be able to use `iw` on the Raspberry PI to do a local scan:

```
iw dev wlan0 scan
```

Either/both of the above should show you which channels are being used within range. Then, as Gilbert says you could change the config to use a less congested channel.

I use a modification of the above command to give me a count of access points against each channel:

```
iw dev wlan0 scan | grep 'primary channel' | sort | uniq -c
```